# Does a memory warning destroy the presenting view controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have an iPad app which has a main view controller, and then a settings view controller. When my main view presents the settings view, I present the settings view in full screen. There is a dismiss button in the settings view, which works - until a memory warning occurs. If a memory warning occurs while the settings button is onscreen, it will refuse to dismiss.

In other words, this works:

- App Launch -> Show Main View -> Show Settings View -> Dismiss Settings View

This doesn't:

- App Launch -> Show Main View -> Show Settings View ->Memory Warning -> Dismiss Settings View

The settings view will just stay there.

I'm running this app on iOS 5 on a first generation iPad. (I'm not supporting iOS 4.)

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

Here's my code for showing the settings view:

```
- (void) showSettings{

    if (!self.settingsViewController) {

    //Create the navigation controller and the root view for the settings panel
    SettingsViewController *settingsRootView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    UINavigationController *settingsView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsRootView];
    [settingsRootView release];

    //Configure the animation and modal style, and the navigation bar's color

    [settingsView.navigationBar setTintColor:kDarkGrayColor];

    //Enable the settings flag
    [self setSettingsIsActive:YES]; 

    //Configure the presentation
    [settingsView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [settingsView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

    self.settingsViewController = settingsView;

    [settingsView release];
    }

    //present and release the settings panel
    [self presentViewController:self.settingsViewController animated:YES completion:^{

    }];

}
```

And here's how I hide it:

```
//This method reloads some stuff and 
- (void) dismissSettings{

    //
    //  ... Reload some other stuff...
    //

    //Dismiss the settings panel
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    //
    //  ... Reload some other stuff...
    //

    }]; 
}
```

Comment: Have you discovered what is giving you the memory warning?  Are you doing anything in any didReceiveMemoryWarning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, a memory warning will not do anything to your view controllers, but it will unload the views of those view controllers that are not currently being displayed on the screen.

In your particular case, I would look for anything on the code from your Settings View Controller that might be referencing something from the view of the main view controller. If that is the case, problably that reference will be nil after the memory warning occurs.

Also, you should verify your implementation of the didReceiveMemoryWarning methods, to see if you're disposing of something that might be needed to dismiss that settings view.

On a low memory condition, all the views from those 'inactive' view controllers will be unloaded. As your `dismissSettings` method is declared on the Main Controller, when it is called it is very possible that all the elements from your main view are nil. I don't know what kind of operations are contained in the "Reload some other stuff" code, but I guess something related to the view is making the method fail.

I would suggest moving all the reloading code related to the view to the `viewDidAppear` method as it will be guaranteed to have the view loaded.

On the other hand, I would recommend you to move implement the dismiss method on the actual setting view controller (remember that it should be something like `[                         self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` as you need to dismiss the navigation controller). At least, this is the way I've always done this and never has failed me. The logic being that I don't want inactive view controllers to run any logic.

Finally, as you mention that you are targeting to iOS 5 and above, I would greatly recommend moving your project to ARC. It's easier to do than what it seems, and once that you have moved, it is truly great.

Another possible reason for your problem is that you are calling to your dismiss method using notifications and that your main controller is unsubscribing from that notifications on the viewDidUnload method. Keep in mind that the viewDidUnload method will be called when the low memory condition triggers!

Comment: Nothing is in the viewDidReceiveMemoryWarning methods except the call to the super implementation

Comment: Ok, and does the Settings View Controller have any reference to the Main View Controller? Also, as most probably the view from the Main View Controller is being deallocated, you should verify what's inside the viewDidUnload method from the Main View Controller.

Comment: Nope, no reference to the main view controller. The hierarchy is: Main Window -> Main View Controller -> Settings View Controller

Comment: I'm assuming you are presenting the Settings View Controller modally. Is that true? How do the methods for showing/dismissing the view controller look like?

Comment: Thanks. I see, there's a navigation controller being presented, instead of the settings one. Where's that dismissSettings method being declared? If it belongs to the settings view controller, it should be `[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`instead of what you have; you need to dismiss the navigation controller, not the settings controller.

Comment: They're both declared in the main view controller.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm not really sure if you get notifications when someone edits and answer. So I just leave this to let you know I added new info to it. Sorry if this is not the correct way to notify.

Comment: Just one more thought: Another possible reason for your problem is that you are calling to your dismiss method using notifications and that your main controller is unsubscribing from that notifications on the viewDidUnload method. Keep in mind that the viewDidUnload method will be called when the low memory condition triggers!

Comment: @flainez-I think that's it! In viewWillUnload, I was removing the main view controller from the notification center. Moving it to dealloc fixed the problem. (Will that break things later?)

Comment: Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow. Take a peek at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and stick around for awhile.

Comment: Moving the removal of the notification to dealloc will be perfectly fine... as long as you subscribe to the notification on the init method. If you subscribe to the notification on the viewDidLoad method, you will end subscribing to it multiple times and that has given me problems in the past.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to find out what is causing the memory warning.  Use Instruments and check for leaks.  If you are using ARC, this should be a problem - but obviously something is seriously wrong for a memory warning to occur.  Fix this and you have fixed your problem.

That said, the OS will shut down applications when memory starts getting short.  Background applications are usually the first to go, but many times if the leak is bad enough, the time period between when background apps are terminated and the time when the running app is also terminated can be short.